# Easy string splitting?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a string I want to split: D017209D019169D019014 into  D017209, D019169, and D019014 with commas in between.

If I have

```
a = D017209D019169D019014
b = a.slice("D")
puts b
```

My result looks like:

```
017209
019169
019014
```

What am I missing?

Comment: a string split function will always remove the terminator.  You want to substrings that begin with 'D'.  A regex would be best here, but honestly I use them so infrequently that I will let someone else suggest the answer in case I make a mistake (no time to test)

Comment: general rule of thumb: use `split` when you know what you want to throw away, use a regular expression when you know what you want to keep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"D017209D019169D019014".scan(/D[^D]*/)
```

Scan returns an array of all the matches, which is exactly what you want here.  The regex simply means D, followed by zero or more non-D's.

Comment: Add a join adds in the commas

"D017209D019169D019014".scan(/D[^D]*/).join(",")  yields"D017209,DD019169,DD019014"

Answer (score 0):

a string split function will always remove the terminator. You want to substrings that begin with 'D'. A regex would be best here

```
a.scan(/D[0-9]*/).each do |line|
  #do stuff with each piece of data
end
```

BTW, as I said in my comment I am absolutely NOT a regex expert, not even good really.  So, if someone finds a gaping whole in this let me know, but it should work with the input you have.